# Add CSS classes to wordpress sub menus in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

```
<ul class="w3-navbar w3-card-2 w3-light-grey">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
   <li class="w3-dropdown-hover">
      <a href="#">Dropdown</a>
      <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-white w3-card-4">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
     </div>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

I have attached classes to parent items

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
                    'theme_location'=>'primary',
                    'menu_class'=>'w3-navbar w3-red w3-card-8 w3-large',
                    'container'=>'w3-container'                    
                     )
             )
```

I am not able to define classes for sub menu items (w3-dropdown-hover) & generating upper code with defined classes to WordPress menus.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Increase the specificity of the CSS Selector. This would help you apply the class for the,.

Comment: If you want to change classes that are generated automatically on WordPress menus, you'll need to make your own[ menu-walker](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker).

Comment: I am not able to understand walker reference. Is there any other way to set this

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add classes (manually) to your menu in wordpress. This feature is hidden by default in wordpress so you must first enable it.

This is how it's done:

1) Go to Apperance->Menus [The screenshot](https://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/17/menu-screen1.png)

2) On the top right corner you can see "Screen options" and "Help" (see The screenshot)

3) Click the "Screen options" now you will see a lot of tick boxes , select the "Css classes" box

4) Now when you click your created menu item you will see a CSS Classes field this is where you can enter your custom class [(Screnshot)](https://codex.wordpress.org/images/f/fe/menu-screen3.png)

Here is one more [Helpful Link](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide) for you describing in detail what you can do with your menu's.